# Ajuda no Calback validationEngine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Estou utilizando o `validationEngine` para uma validação de formulário e envio após tudo preenchido. Até aí tudo bem. Porém preciso recuperar alguns dados do cadastro após a confirmação.

Assim que o usuário preenche os dados, ele submete o formulário, os dados serão gravados no banco. Até aí está tudo certo, porém quando ele submete o formulário ele é processado em uma janela Modal, e eu preciso que o retorno nesta janela Modal venha com alguns dados que o cliente preencheu para mostrar a ele uma resposta amigável .

> Exemplo- (Parabéns **fulano de tal**, seu cadastro foi realizado com
>   sucesso, um e-mail será enviado para **seuemail@seudominio.com** com
>   as informações de acesso!)

A resposta do Calback tem que ser sempre **true**, e eu gostaria de receber no status mais dados de retorno, senão não funciona, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

```
jQuery("#form").validationEngine({
   scroll: false,
   ajaxFormValidation: true,
   ajaxFormValidationMethod: "post",
   ajaxFormValidationURL: "phpajax/processa.php",      
   onAjaxFormComplete: ajaxValidationCallback,     
});

function ajaxValidationCallback(status, form, options){
   if (console) 
      console.log(status);
      alert(status)
   if (status === true) {
      alert("Ok");
   }
}
```